# SCCM deleted deployment still available in the client Software Center

Tags: sccm

in SCCM I created an application and then deployed to my pc, but as it was wrong I decided to delete the deployment.
From that moment I continuously receive notification on my pc to install that application. I cannot find a way to delete it, to let it forget it.
I already clear out the sccm cache on my pc without success.
Is there anything I can do to reset completely sccm client ?
thanks

Comment: Normally this is more a policy than a cache thing. So if you do a machine policy update as well as a application deployment update cycle in the client it still prompts this after a few minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the (sccm client) local policy's? 
Try using: "control smscfgrc">actions>Machine Policy retrieval and evaluation cycle